# Orbital but stationary motion

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, equilibrium

Is there a place between the Moon and Earth where an object can rest freely and revolve with the Moon? What is that called?

[image]

Comment: You mean Earth-Moon libration points? See e.g. http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1966SSRv....5..210S ("Earth-Moon Libration Points: Theory, Existence, and Applications" Authors: Steg, L. & de Vries, J. P.
Journal: Space Science Reviews, Volume 5, Issue 2, pp.210-233)

Comment: I thinks so see picture.

Comment: Like John Rennie correctly said, L1 isn't a good one, but L4 and L5 which form a triangle with Earth and Moon seems to be reasonably stable to park a spacecraft in there. One would still need some amount of control to counteract perturbations.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are several points where you could remain stationary with respect to the Earth and the Moon. These are known as the [Lagrange points](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/lagpt.html#c1).

The Lagrange point directly between the Earth and the Moon is known as the $L_1$ point. Note however that this is a point of unstable equilibrium. In practice perturbations from the other bodies in the Solar system would quickly move you out of the $L_1$ point.